# Unexpected Result in complex Query while migration from MySQL to SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Recently, we are migrating our project from MySQL to SQL Server.

We have used tool SSMA - SQL Server Migration Assistant.

We have recovered our data to it fullest. However, somewhat changes made after.

There has been a problem in SQL Stored Procedure.

In MySQL :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE
 `generate_file_outward`(IN presentday int)
BEGIN

select 67,destination_bank_ifsc,party_account_type,
    case ecs_account_type  when 1 then 'LON' when 2 
then 'REC' when 3 then 'LOK' when 4 then 'DEM'
 when 5 then 'MSI' else 'BGL' END as ecs_account_type,
    party_account_no,left(party_account_name,40) as party_account_name,'XXXXXXXX',requestor_id,sponsor_bank_name1,
id,mandate_request_id,mandate_amount,umrn_no from outward_master
where checker_flag=1 and status_flag=1 and 
umrn_no is not null and return_flag=0 and   requestor_id in ('XXXX00004000006207','XXXX00000000022678','XXXX00000000022702') 
and (to_date >= from_date  OR DATE(to_date)='0000-00-00') 
    AND (DATE(to_date)>=DATE(NOW()) 
OR DATE(to_date)='0000-00-00') and 
DATE(from_date)<=DATE(NOW()) and ecs_day=presentday and 
month(now())= if(mandate_frequency='YEAR',month(from_date+INTERVAL 12 MONTH),
    if(mandate_frequency='QURT',month(from_date+INTERVAL 3 MONTH),month(now())));
END
```

However, It turned out to be failed in SQL Server.

We have been playing around the query and couldn't generate the same results in SQL Server.

SSMA generated some functions and converted query to like this

```
USE [files]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [files].[generate_file_outward]    Script Date: 10/24/2019 11:33:07 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
/*
*   SSMA informational messages:
*   M2SS0003: The following SQL clause was ignored during conversion:
*   DEFINER = `root`@`localhost`.
*/

ALTER PROCEDURE [files].[generate_file_outward]  
   @presentday int
AS 
   BEGIN

      SET  XACT_ABORT  ON

      SET  NOCOUNT  ON

      /*
      *   SSMA warning messages:
      *   M2SS0219: Converted operator may not work exactly the same as in MySQL

      *   SSMA informational messages:
      *   M2SS0052: string literal was converted to NUMERIC literal
      *   M2SS0052: string literal was converted to NUMERIC literal
      */

      SELECT 
         67, 
         outward_master.destination_bank_ifsc, 
         outward_master.party_account_type, 
         CASE outward_master.ecs_account_type
            WHEN 1 THEN 'LON'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'REC'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'LOK'
            WHEN 4 THEN 'DEM'
            WHEN 5 THEN 'MSI'
            ELSE N'BGL'
         END AS ecs_account_type, 
         outward_master.party_account_no, 
         left(outward_master.party_account_name, 40) AS party_account_name, 
         'xxxxxxxxxxx', 
         outward_master.requestor_id, 
         outward_master.sponsor_bank_name1, 
         outward_master.ID, 
         outward_master.mandate_request_id, 
         outward_master.mandate_amount, 
         outward_master.umrn_no
      FROM files.outward_master
      WHERE 
         outward_master.checker_flag = 1 AND 
         outward_master.status_flag = 1 AND 
         outward_master.umrn_no IS NOT NULL AND 
         outward_master.return_flag = 0 AND 
         outward_master.requestor_id IN ( 'xxxx00004000006207', 'xxxx00000000022678', 'xxxx00000000022702' ) AND 
         (outward_master.to_date >= outward_master.from_date OR CAST(CONVERT(varchar(10), outward_master.to_date, 112) AS int) = 0000) AND 
         (outward_master.to_date >= getdate() OR CAST(CONVERT(varchar(10), outward_master.to_date, 112) AS int) = 0000) AND 
         outward_master.from_date <= getdate() AND 
         outward_master.ecs_day = @presentday AND 
         datepart(MONTH, getdate()) = 
         CASE 
            WHEN (outward_master.mandate_frequency = 'YEAR') THEN datepart(MONTH, m2ss.num_to_date((CAST(CONVERT(varchar(10), outward_master.from_date, 112) AS int) + NULL)))
            ELSE 
               CASE 
                  WHEN (outward_master.mandate_frequency = 'QURT') THEN datepart(MONTH, m2ss.num_to_date((CAST(CONVERT(varchar(10), outward_master.from_date, 112) AS int) + NULL)))
                  ELSE datepart(MONTH, getdate())
               END
         END

   END
```

Self Function :

```
USE [files]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [m2ss].[num_to_date]    Script Date: 10/25/2019 12:06:05 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [m2ss].[num_to_date](@val NUMERIC(38,0)) RETURNS DATE
AS
  BEGIN
    RETURN cast(m2ss.num_to_datetime(@val) AS DATE)
  END
```

We could not derive the same results as per query in MySQL.

What might have went wrong?

Here's our sample data

```
https://ibb.co/y5G1XTY
```

Connotations :

```
ADHO - As and When Presented, YEAR = Yearly, MNTH = Monthly, QURT = Quarterly
```

Our records generating dates are (4,7,10,15,22,28) so Input is Present Day.

We have built a query in MySQL however, not working efficiently in SQL Server, knowing that in both DB syntax are quite different, Any suggestions?

Comment: Nobody can answer this without some more details. You say you don't get the same output. What output do you get that isn't the same? You need to share some sample data of some sort here as nobody is a human sql parser. Is it the function that isn't the same? Or what is different?

Comment: There has been complication in this part. (to_date >= from_date  OR DATE(to_date)='0000-00-00') 
    AND (DATE(to_date)>=DATE(NOW()) 
OR DATE(to_date)='0000-00-00') and 
DATE(from_date)<=DATE(NOW()) and ecs_day=presentday and 
month(now())= if(mandate_frequency='YEAR',month(from_date+INTERVAL 12 MONTH),
    if(mandate_frequency='QURT',month(from_date+INTERVAL 3 MONTH),month(now())));

Comment: sql server does not zero date time so to_date field is set to null.

Comment: what sort of data you require?

Comment: the `DATE(to_date)='0000-00-00')` is about the only logical part which might explain dfferent results between MySQL and MSSQL besides that at first seight i dont't see something else that could cause it ... But see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You should not put code or question clarification in the comments. The formatting is horrific and since it belongs with the question you should include it in the question.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "sql server does not zero date time". But I think it around this "CAST(CONVERT(varchar(10), outward_master.to_date, 112) AS int) = 0000". That will never work the way you are trying. If you use CAST and/or CONVERT you should be consistent and not use both in the same derived value. This just isn't how date comparisons work in sql server. A 0 when converted to a date is '1900-01-01', not 0. What value is in that table to represent your zero date? This is where sample data comes into play. Just guessing blindly is not good.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more clear what you're asking, to show exactly what isn't the same (using sample data and examples from both MYSQL and SQL Server), and realize that SQL Server does not have a built-in "NOW()" function, etc.

Comment: https://ibb.co/y5G1XTY Here's what our data look like

Comment: @SeanLange Provided Data in Question.

Comment: Pictures of data are nearly worthless. [Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) But it seems to me that what you should be doing is inserting a NULL when you don't have a date. That is what NULL is for. Then change up your procedure to check "IS NULL" instead of the current = 0000 logic

Comment: We Solved Query. Thanks @SeanLange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT     destination_bank_ifsc, party_account_type, 
                      CASE ecs_account_type WHEN 1 THEN 'LON' WHEN 2 THEN 'REC' WHEN 3 THEN 'LOK' WHEN 4 THEN 'DEM' WHEN 5 THEN 'MSI' ELSE 'BGL' END AS ecs_account_type,
                       party_account_no, LEFT(party_account_name, 40) AS party_account_name, requestor_id, sponsor_bank_name1, ID, mandate_request_id, mandate_amount, 
                      umrn_no
FROM         outward_master
WHERE     (checker_flag = 1) AND (status_flag = 1) AND (umrn_no IS NOT NULL) AND (return_flag = 0) AND (requestor_id IN ('xxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxx', 
                      'xxxxxxxxx')) AND (to_date >= from_date OR
                      to_date IS NULL) AND (to_date >= CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) OR
                      to_date IS NULL) AND (from_date <= CONVERT(date, GETDATE())) AND (ecs_day = 4) AND (DATEPART(month, GETDATE()) 
                      = CASE WHEN mandate_frequency = 'YEAR' THEN DATEPART(month, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(month, 12, from_date))) 
                      WHEN mandate_frequency = 'QURT' THEN DATEPART(month, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(month, 3, from_date))) ELSE DATEPART(month, getdate()) END)
```

It is good do learn, also all rdms databases syntax are different.